# How to handle config files (or db creditentials) in git branches?

Tags: php, git, deployment, git-merge, git-rebase

I have a simple web app. I have a production database for the live version, and a test database for development. I store the database credentials in a config file, like so:

```
<?php
return array(
    'hostname' => 'myhostname',
    'username' => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'dbname' => 'myLiveDB',
);
?>
```

This file is tracked by git. On the development branch I want to have file with the same name, just with different credentials. I do my work in this branch, test things out and then merge into master when I want to deploy a newer version.

I never want to see this file change during a merge/rebase operation. Each branch should always keep its own version and it should only be updated by committing directly onto the branch.

What I have considered so far:

- `.gitattributes` files with `merge=ours` for the config file + `git config --global merge.ours.driver true`. I don't think this works for rebase, which is a problem. I'm also not sure if every other developer working on this would need to update their config manually, or is there a way to change that setting on a repository level?
- ditch the config file, rewrite everything to use environment variables. set them manually for the server and for each dev.
- have a `config_test.php` and a `config_prod.php` in the repository. When deploying, have the script take a look at what branch we are deploying from and copy the the correct file while renaming it to `config.php`

Comment: I think the third option is the best one. Two different config files :)

Comment: Am I just being stupid or does this sound really simpel: Just edit 1 config on the test branch, commit it. Edit the config again in the other branch and commit it. And put the config in .gitingore, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Mike does gitignore have any effect on files that are already tracked?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the third point might be good and a right method. In spring-boot (java) we used to have different profiles in yamal file (application.yml) with names like dev, test, prod etc and spring itself will take the exact file when it is running in that specific environment. Check something like is there or not. 
But in your case, just think whether you need a file which is under git or not.
Think that you have a file under your home directory (say `/home/myname/testfile/development.properties`). And change the code so that, if this properties file exists then take it otherwise take the other one.